# How to validate email address and website in commnet

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to validate email address and website in comment box. When someone writes comment in comment box and after submission check if email address or website found in comment remove that email and address.

I have put below regular expression for email.

`` "/(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/" ``

above expression validates email address but I want to validate like ***email[at]email[dot]com, email{at}email{dot}com, email(at)email(dot)com***

Same for website validation I used below expression

`"/((((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/)|www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\/\S*)?)/"`

But I want to validate website like ***website[dot]com, www[dot]website[dot]com***

Comment: If you can use PHP then you could use normal string functions, instead [expanding an already over complicated regular expression](https://hackernoon.com/for-the-love-of-jeez-stop-using-regex-in-software-3a916e2c5987). What you want to do is not really that complicated.

Comment: People will always find a way around it anyways so why bother? I could just write `email $ domain & com` and any human will understand it's an email but fool your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is, where you have the validation of `@` and `.` character in email or `.` in weburl, you need to enhance your regex and put the alternatives to `@` character as you are expecting. So,

```
@ should be written as (?:@|[[({]at[\]})])
```

And,

```
\. should be written as (?:\.|[[{(]dot[\]})])
```

wherever you have them in your regex and then it will also filter those strings as well.

Here is a modified regex for email.

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*\")(?:@|[[({]at[\]})])(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.|[[{(]dot[\]})]))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

**[Regex Demo for email](https://regex101.com/r/4rbG5p/1)**

Same way you can replace `.` from your website regex and your modified regex becomes this,

```
(?:(?:(?:http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/)|www(?:\.|[[{(]dot[\]})]))(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.-]|[[{(]dot[\]})])+(?:\.|[[{(]dot[\]})])[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\/\S*)?
```

**[Regex Demo for web url](https://regex101.com/r/f8ZhJg/1)**

Now besides matching of `[dot]`, `{dot}` and `(dot)`, the regex will also match `[dot}` and similar and as you are trying to detect such strings further, hence matching these strings will be an added advantage, rather than a problem unless the context was otherwise.